# WordPress custom block: Link saved in database not retrieved when editing post

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm creating my first custom block for wordpress which must add two buttons and I need to insert the link of the two buttons. But after updating the post the link is saved, however if I enter the post again to edit, the link appears empty, it does not retrieve the link saved in the database. See my edit.js code

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';

import { useBlockProps, URLInputButton } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';

import './editor.scss';

registerBlockType( 'my-custom-block', {
    // ...
    attributes: {
        link1: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'attribute',
            attribute: 'href',
            selector: '.btn-afil-text-card a:first-child'
        },
        link2: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'attribute',
            attribute: 'href',
            selector: '.btn-afil-text-card a:last-child'
        }
    },
    

} );

export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {

    return (

            <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
  <div className="card-afil">
    <div className="btn-afil">
      <span className="btn-afil-img">
        <img src="https://www.adoromaquiagem.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/amazon.webp" />
      </span>
      <span className="btn-afil-text-card">
        <URLInputButton
          url={attributes.link1} // Assumes you have 'link1' attribute defined in attributes
          onChange={(link1) => setAttributes({  link1:link1 })}
        />
      </span>
    </div>

    <div className="btn-afil">
      <span className="btn-afil-img">
        <img src="https://www.adoromaquiagem.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/beleza-na-web.webp" />
      </span>
      <span className="btn-afil-text-card">
        <URLInputButton
          url={attributes.link2} // Assumes you have 'link2' attribute defined in attributes
          onChange={(link2) => setAttributes({  link2:link2 })}
        />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

            
    );
}
```

And my code in save.js

```
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';

registerBlockType( 'my-custom-block', {
    // ...
    attributes: {
        link1: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'attribute',
            attribute: 'href',
            selector: '.btn-afil-text-card a:first-child'
        },
        link2: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'attribute',
            attribute: 'href',
            selector: '.btn-afil-text-card a:last-child'
        }
    },
    // ...
} );

export default function save({ attributes }) {

    const { link1, link2 } = attributes;

    return (
        
            <div>
              <div className="card-afil">
                <div className="btn-afil">
                  <span className="btn-afil-img">
                    <img src="https://www.adoromaquiagem.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/amazon.webp" />
                  </span>
                  <span className="btn-afil-text-card">
                    <a href={link1} className="btn-afil-text">Ver Preço</a>
                  </span>
                </div>
            
                <div className="btn-afil">
                  <span className="btn-afil-img">
                    <img src="https://www.adoromaquiagem.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/beleza-na-web.webp" />
                  </span>
                  <span className="btn-afil-text-card">
                    <a href={link2} className="btn-afil-text">Ver Preço</a>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        
    );
}
```

In summary, if I save the link and publish it, when opening the post the links that were saved appear normally. But if I need to edit such links and go to edit post, the links appear empty. If I insert a new link it updates correctly. But I need to edit the link already saved before, because the way it is can confuse editors.

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

I tried reading the documentation to be able to edit the button links, but I couldn't find anything specific. I don't know what to look for or where to find this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever an issue appears while testing a block, the first place to check is your browser console. In this case, when I tested your code with links as "a.com" and "b.com", the browser console error is:

```error
Block validation: Expected attribute `href` of value `a.com`, saw `b.com`.
(anonymous) @ logger.js:17
(ano...

Content generated by `save` function:

<div><div class="card-afil"><div class="btn-afil"><span class="btn-afil-img"><img src="https://www.adoromaquiagem.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/amazon.webp"/></span><span class="btn-afil-text-card"><a href="a.com" class="btn-afil-text">Ver Preço</a></span></div><div class="btn-afil"><span class="btn-afil-img"><img src="https://www.adoromaquiagem.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/beleza-na-web.webp"/></span><span class="btn-afil-text-card"><a href="a.com" class="btn-afil-text">Ver Preço</a></span></div></div></div>

Content retrieved from post body:

<div><div class="card-afil"><div class="btn-afil"><span class="btn-afil-img"><img src="https://www.adoromaquiagem.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/amazon.webp"/></span><span class="btn-afil-text-card"><a href="a.com" class="btn-afil-text">Ver Preço</a></span></div><div class="btn-afil"><span class="btn-afil-img"><img src="https://www.adoromaquiagem.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/beleza-na-web.webp"/></span><span class="btn-afil-text-card"><a href="b.com" class="btn-afil-text">Ver Preço</a></span></div></div></div>
```

From this, we can see the issue is the selector for the attributes. If you look at your HTML code, the selector `.btn-afil-text-card a:first-child` is actually **the same** as `.btn-afil-text-card a:last-child`. Because the link classes are not unique, both are not of children of `.btn-afil-text-card`. The first link is the *first* and *last* child, the second link is **also** the *first* and *last* child, replacing the previous value, causing the block validation error. To use first/last child, you would have needed to select from `.card-afil .btn-afil`.

**Solution:**
Use unique selectors for your links. Don't rely on selecting by class, as if you change the classname or the HTML structure, the same issue occurs. Stick with a unique selector like ID that won't change.

```js
registerBlockType( 'my-custom-block', {
    // ...
    attributes: {
        link1: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'attribute',
            attribute: 'href',
            selector: '#link1' // unique ID
        },
        link2: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'attribute',
            attribute: 'href',
            selector: '#link2' // unique ID
        }
    },
...
}

export default function save({ attributes }) {

    const { link1, link2 } = attributes;

    return (        
            <div>
            ...
                  <span className="btn-afil-text-card">
                    <a id="link1" href={link1} className="btn-afil-text">Ver Preço</a>
                  </span>
                  ...
                  <span className="btn-afil-text-card">
                    <a id="link2" href={link2} className="btn-afil-text">Ver Preço</a>
                  </span>
            ...
            </div>
    )
}
```